# Access phone number in TelephonyCallback - Android

Tags: android, deprecated, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

`PhoneStateListener`'s `onCallStateChanged` took the state of the phone call and the number being called as parameters:

```kotlin
val telephonyManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager

telephonyManager.listen(
    object : PhoneStateListener() {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber)
        }
    },
    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE
)
```

After the deprecation of `listen()` and `PhoneStateListener`, the suggested way to listen to phone calls is through `registerTelephonyCallback()`, that takes an `Executor` and a `TelephonyCallback` as parameters, the problem is that `TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener`'s `onCallStateChanged` only takes the call state as parameter:

```kotlin
telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(
    context.mainExecutor,
    object : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
            // WHERE IS PHONE NUMBER?
        }
    }
)
```

I absolutely need to know the phone number being called in order to make my app work properly.
Does someone know how to obtain it using `TelephonyCallback` or, at least, without using deprecated methods?

Comment: Any news on this topic? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I found something, I just wrote a post about it

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `CallScreeningService`, that is available from API 24, but unusable until API 29 because of `callDirection`:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class PhoneCallScreening : CallScreeningService() {
    override fun onScreenCall(callDetails: Call.Details) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (callDetails.callDirection == Call.Details.DIRECTION_OUTGOING) {
                val phoneNumber = callDetails.handle.schemeSpecificPart

                PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                    .edit()
                    .putString(CALLED_PHONE_NUMBER_KEY, phoneNumber)
                    .apply()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use this, your app has to become the default one for call screening:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public void requestRole() {
    RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PHONE_SCREENING_REQUEST_ID);
}
```

I don't know if you can access any other information about the call besides the phone number, I currently save the phone number in SharedPreferences and then access it in the new `PhoneStateListener`'s `onCallStateChanged`.

As I said before, this solution is only possible from API 29, for lower API versions you have to use the deprecated way, I think is the only one to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have accessed it using intent:

```
val incomingNumber: String? = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
```

https://github.com/gulsenkeskin/phone_call_demo/blob/main/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/phone_call_demo/MainActivity.kt